# WordPress subpages in tabs

Tags: wordpress, tabs

For a website, I would like to add all subpages with dynamic content (images, lists, columns...) in tabs on the parent page. The tabs may be very simple, like [this](http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal).

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
        <label for="tab1">Description</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content"> THE CONTENT </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="ta2" checked />
        <label for="tab2">Description</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content"> THE CONTENT </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Accompanied by some CSS.

How can I modify this code to get the title and content by the WordPress subpages?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom loop. First you have to do a WP_Query to get your subpages. I don't know your structure so this snippet is only example:

```
$subpages = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'post_parent'    => $this_page,
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
) );
```

Then you can loop trow this query something like this:

```
<ul class="tabs">

<?php 
    global $post;
    while ( $subpages->have_posts() ) : $subpages->the_post();
?>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" checked />
        <label for="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </label>
        <div id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" class="tab-content"> 
            <?php the_content();?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</ul>
```

You should place a similar loop into your template or where you want to display the subpages. This loop will iterate throw you query which contains the subpages and set the global $post object so it always contain the current subpage in this loop. Then it will print your requested HTML structure and it will use the title of the page, the slug of the page and the content of the page. After the iteration it will reset a query and unset the $post global variable.